# Same composer scripts with different PHP binary

Tags: php, composer-php, command-line-interface

I've got two environments in which I would like to use composer scripts. Locally I've got `php` binary registred, but at one of my hosters I've got `php` and `php_cli` and need to use the **php_cli** one because of different php.ini settings.

**My question:** Am I able to tell composer to call php scripts with different PHP binaries, depending on the current environment?

My "script.bat" file contains such variables, which look promising:

```
:RUN
"%PHPBIN%" "@bin_dir@\script" %*
```

but the unix "script" file just contain the usual hashbang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

I tried such calls like:

```
PHPBIN="php_cli" composer create-project ...
```

or

```
php_cli /path/to/composer.phar create-project ...
```

but without success. Any help is very appreciated! Thanks.

**Update:** I've created a feature request on GitHub for composer/composer: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `@php`, which resolves to the PHP process currently being used.

`composer.json`:

```
{
     "scripts": {
         "test": [
             "@php script.php",
             "phpunit"
         ]
     }
}
```

Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#executing-php-scripts

Comment: Hehe... Thanks. Actually this `@php` syntax has been introduced because of my issue (see link in question), I've opened after I did not get any answers here^^

Btw. this @php syntax does not fix issues on Windows. You can't call a windows batch file with php. On unix with shebang, this is posisble. See my last comment in this issue. I've referenced a composer package of my own, there it is also possible to call those binaries on Windows :)